# Show content through content query web part and than show it in calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I want to show all my data I have brought from content query web part and show it in calendar view.
Kindly help !

Comment: Why you want to fetch data from content query? Please explain you requirement.

Comment: I have fetched the tasks of all the clients , through content query web part . Now I want to show those tasks in calendar view and inside calendar those those should be of different colour based on the client name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calendar view` of task list.
For different color, add custom javascript or css based on client id/name.